# How to remove content around and including curly brackets with regex?

Tags: python, regex

Feel this is a common use case for but i can't find too much help online.

Given a test string like "Hello my name is \name{John} \name{Doe}", i would like to remove all curly brackets *and the content around them* (white space and period is excluding), but keep the content between the brackets. The expected output would be "Hello my name is John Doe".

Comment: Check [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/0O5HFL/1) ?

Comment: @SaSkY oh that looks like it works. Can you explain? If not, i can refer to the explanation on the demo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
[^ .]*{|}[^ .]*
```

`[^ .]*{`  ---> `[^ .]*` zero or more character except spaces and dots, note there is a space after `^`, followed by a literal `{`

`|` OR

`}[^ .]*` ---> a literal `}`, followed by `[^ .]*` zero or more character except spaces and dots.

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/dtknyc/1)